# Achieve AYVibrantButton effect with Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

I have a project that uses the 3rd party API called [AYVibrantButton](https://github.com/a1anyip/AYVibrantButton) (please take a look in the link).

The problem is that this API doesn't support Swift 3, so I'm searching for a way to achieve the same effect ("Invert style with vibrancy effect") with Swift 3 (another 3rd party API or a way to create it without using any 3rd parties, the easier one).

Anyone knows?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see, it is an Objective-C library. You just have to import the .h file using a bridging header and you should be good to go. Objective-C libraries does not need to support swift, as far as I know. I actually use Obj-C version of libraries that doesn't work well with swift 3.

Comment: @varijkap Thanks!